# Верстка и метод anti-aliasing Crisp

Tags: css3, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте

Шрифт Myriad Pro. Метод anti-aliasing Crisp.
Как можно при помощи css сверстать такое?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью CSS можно только в браузерах на движке webkit( Safari, Chrome ), с помощью свойства [-webkit-font-smoothing](http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing/). В FF раньше была поддержка свойства font-smooth, однако потом была удалена. Про поддержку в IE говорить не приходится и так всё понятно.